# mySQL subqueries

Tags: mysql

i wrote this code which has the following result and now I want to sum the result of the two rows obtained after the union.
Any idea how can i do that (i mean i need another select on this new "table").
Any help is appreciated

```
SELECT Date_format(`creation`, '%Y-%m-%d') AS short_date,
       Sum(`param7`)                       AS time_spent_in_sessions,
       Count(*)                            AS nb_of_sessions
FROM   `f_colony_ios_play_resume_pn__20120823`
WHERE  `id` IN ( '22965', '22966' )

UNION

SELECT Date_format(`creation`, '%Y-%m-%d') AS short_date,
       Sum(`param8`)                       AS time_spent_in_sessions,
       Count(*)                            AS nb_of_sessions
FROM   `f_colony_ios_play_resume_pn__20120823`
WHERE  `id` IN ( '22970', '22971' )

-----------------------------
result:
    short_date       time_spent_in_sessions      nb_of_sessions
    2012-08-23               7                        2
    2012-08-23               10                       1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT short_date, SUM(time_spent_in_sessions), SUM(nb_of_sessions) 
FROM (both your queries here) AS subquerytable
```

I think this is the way to go...

Comment: #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias
 <--------
i have to put an alias for the both queries here?

Comment: ok, i have to put an AS 'something' after the from clause, when the bracket is closed

Comment: Correct, I forgot about that! :-)